# Areodynamics of ancient flying machines. Did they really worked for them?

Tags: aerodynamics

If any modern day aerodynamic scholars by chance  gone through rig vedas of hindu mythology. It has been described like below.

> "jumping into space speedily with a craft using fire and water ...
>   containing twelve stamghas (pillars), one wheel, three machines, 300
>   pivots, and 60 instruments."

Reference from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimana

Is there any scientifical proofs that those aerodynamic principles would have worked for them or just a myth?

Comment: Mythology doesn't need scientific foundations, but it's easy to claim there are some, as narrative are not very detailed, so many interpretations are possible. But that's not scientific either. It's like [Nostradamus predictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostradamus).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a few points:

- You are yourself conceding that these are from mythology. If something is from mythology, it is (almost) certainly a myth.
- Description of a fictional flying machine and explaining their principles of operation are completely different. To the best of my knowledge, none of these texts even try to explain the principle of operation.
- Actually, there was a [study carried out on one of these texts](http://cgpl.iisc.ernet.in/site/Portals/0/Publications/ReferedJournal/ACriticalStudyOfTheWorkVaimanikaShastra.pdf), which thoroughly debunked the claims made and concluded,

> ... the planes described above are (at) the best poor concoctions, rather than expressions of something real.None of the planes has properties or capabilities of being flown; the geometries are unimaginably horrendous from the point of view of flying; and the principles of propulsion make then  resist rather than assist flying.